# Uploading all files in a folder with Flex

Tags: apache-flex, jsp

I want to make a file uploader with Flex.
However, I want it to select a folder and upload all the files in the folder.
It would be much better if I can actually check the files before uploding.

I'm using Flex with JSP in the back-end. 
Is there a way to do this?

So far, all I found from googling around is how to make file uploader for uploading a single file.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can upload multiple files using the [FileReferenceList](http://livedocs.adobe.com/flex/3/langref/flash/net/FileReferenceList.html) class. There is an example at the bottom of the link.

> When the FileReferenceList.browse() method is called and the user has selected one or more files from the dialog box that the browse() method opens, this property is populated with an array of FileReference objects, each of which represents the files the user selected. You can then use this array to upload each file with the FileReference.upload()method. You must upload one file at a time.